# non maximum suppression in C

Tags: c, image-processing, non-maximum-suppression

Im trying to implement a non maximum suppression function in C.

Non-maximum suppression is a non-linear filter that suppresses all of the values in the window that are not the maximum value. Consider a 5-element sequence w[n] that has the following values: w[n] = [25 10 31 50 19].
The largest value in the window is 50. Applying non-maximum suppression will produce the following output: w'[n] = [0 0 0 50 0].
Following is my code so far:

```
void  NMS(int width, int height, double *input,double *output,double H,double W){

for (int y = 0; y <height; y++){
    for (int x = 0; x <width; x++){
      double r_max;
        int ind = x*height + y;
        for(int yy=0;yy<H;yy++){
            for(int xx=0;xx<W;xx++){
                int k_ind=xx*H+yy;
                if (input[ind+k_ind]>r_max){
                    r_max=input[ind+k_ind];
                }
                else if(input[ind+k_ind]<r_max)
                    output[ind+k_ind]=0.0;
            }
        }
     }
  }    
}
```

int height, width: they are the height and width of the double *input matrix which holds the image data. double *output stores the new values and displays a new image. H and W are the window i want to apply the non maximum suppression in.

I'm finding the max value in the HxW window and assigning it to r_max. But suppose that r_max is 0 at the start. It finds the value, say 4, in the first index and, say 6, in the 2nd index. Now i'm updating r_max but how do i make the previous index, which had the value 4, equal to 0? Im confused as to how to keep track of the previous index.

Please ask for any clarifications if needed. Thank you all!

Comment: Review `double r_max; ... if (input[ind+k_ind]>r_max){`.  What is the value of `r_max` the first time `if (input[ind+k_ind]>r_max){` is execute?

Comment: The simplest solution is to scan the matrix twice, once to find the max and once to set things to zero.  An alternative is to keep a list (array) of positions with the current max value, so if the maximum changes, you can go back and zero those positions with the old maximum, and then empty the list, and continue to the end.  Whether that's actually faster than scanning the input twice depends on sizes and allocation mechanisms — many times, the overhead of maintaining the list will outweigh the benefit of not rescanning the entire image.

Comment: R_max has no initial value. I could set it to 0 for the initial value.

Comment: I tried scanning the array twice. But I was not able to get the value of r_max out of the last two for loops. I think the value can only be accessed inside the for loops the variable is in. Unless I'm wrong? I added two additional for loops right after the 3rd and the 4th loop ended but it didn't work.